# A x meters distanced point from a waypoint of my route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Given a route from A to B through WaypointA and WaypointB, and a magnitude in meters, say, 150m. Is it possible to query Google Maps API V3 in order to get/retrieve a point (LatLong) representing WaypointA-position + 150m ahead routing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible to calculate that point certainly.  [Example with a marker at 9.5km and 64.8km along a route from the DirectionsService](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html) (uses a ported version of Mike Williams' epoly utility)

Comment: Oh I see. Exploring epoly utility's code, we can see the method: **`GetPointAtDistance(metres)`**, which _Returns the GLatLng of a point at the specified distance along the path_

Thanks!